# Eloquent: How to 'WhereNotNull' from a ::with( ) result

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm running the following query that has a `with()` relation.

```
$logbook_objectives = self::whereIn('lobjective_id',  $logbook_objectives_ids)
    ->with(['objective' => function($q) use ($course_objective_ids){
         $q->select(['objective_id', 'objective_code', 'objective_name'])
           ->whereIn('objective_id', $course_objective_ids)
           ->whereIn('objective_parent', $course_objective_ids, 'or');
     }])
     ->withCount(['entryObjectives' => function ($q) use ($learner_id) {
          $q->where('created_by', $learner_id);
     }])
     ->get();
```

Sometimes the the returned 'objective' field is null because of the rules within the `with` function. How do I remove the results that have `objective` = `null`?

I tried using `->whereHas('objective')` before the `->get()` but it doesn't change anything. Is there another way to evaluate if the `with` function returned null keeping the same query?

Solutions I have on my head:

- Use join instead, so I can evaluate null results in the same query.
- Use a foreach look verifying if the `objective` field is null and remove found results from my returned list.

Comment: A `foreach` loop is the only solution I see. In the latest versions of Laravel, you can use `unsetRelation()` to remove the `objective` relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to use a `whereHas` together with the `with` function. The query would be:

```
$logbook_objectives = self::whereIn('lobjective_id',  $logbook_objectives_ids)
    ->with(['objective' => function($q) use ($course_objective_ids){
         $q->select(['objective_id', 'objective_code', 'objective_name'])
           ->whereIn('objective_id', $course_objective_ids)
           ->whereIn('objective_parent', $course_objective_ids, 'or');
     }])
     ->whereHas('objective', function($q) use ($course_objective_ids){
         $q->select(['objective_id', 'objective_code', 'objective_name'])
           ->whereIn('objective_id', $course_objective_ids)
           ->whereIn('objective_parent', $course_objective_ids, 'or');
     })
     ->withCount(['entryObjectives' => function ($q) use ($learner_id) {
          $q->where('created_by', $learner_id);
     }])
     ->get();
```

In that case only rows that the `objective` exists will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

If objective table has 'objective_id' or any other key as primary key then place that key in whereNotNull just as given below:

```
$logbook_objectives = self::whereIn('lobjective_id',  $logbook_objectives_ids)
    ->with(['objective' => function($q) use ($course_objective_ids){
         $q->select(['objective_id', 'objective_code', 'objective_name'])
           ->whereIn('objective_id', $course_objective_ids)
           ->whereIn('objective_parent', $course_objective_ids, 'or')->whereNotNull('objective_id');
     }])
     ->withCount(['entryObjectives' => function ($q) use ($learner_id) {
          $q->where('created_by', $learner_id);
     }])
     ->get();
```

Comment: That won't work either. The rules inside the `with` won't affect the main query and results with `objective = null` are still being retrieved.